# I would like to fix the following error: "Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

While testing the proximity sensor, the following is displayed in the error log
"Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0"

If there is a better way, please let me know. please.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProximitySensor: View {
    @State private var theNumber = 30
    
    let TTS = TextToSpeech()
    let device = UIDevice.current
    
    init() {
        device.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(theNumber)")
                .id("theNumber" + "\(theNumber)")
                .font(.system(size: 100))
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .italic()
        }.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
            for: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification), perform: { _ in
                if UIDevice.current.proximityState {
                    theNumber += 1
                    let toHan = getOrdinaryNumber(theNumber)
                    TTS.speak(text: toHan)
                }
            }
        )
        
    }
}
```

I am attaching the error log. Every time I test the proximity sensor, an error log appears one line at a time.

```
2023-10-03 02:37:36.095925+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:36.596294+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:37.108900+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:37.509284+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:38.126632+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:38.625794+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:39.144115+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:39.544358+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:40.060652+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:40.670889+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:41.381416+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:41.882057+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:42.800046+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:43.000682+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:43.919510+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:44.219041+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:37:44.937449+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:08.933263+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:09.343950+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:09.844229+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:10.261107+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:12.062828+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
2023-10-03 02:41:12.479038+0900 PushUp[40969:7329614] [EventDispatcher] Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 14; contextId: 0x0
```

Comment: Is your app crashing? On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Sorry for the short explanation. The proximity sensor works well and the app does not crash. Every time the proximity sensor is tested, it is displayed in the error log. 
I can't find which line is causing the error.

Comment: For readability, please [edit] your question with additional info.

Comment: Getting similar message recently (Xcode 15.0.1, simulator iOS 17.0): Found no UIEvent for backing event of type: 3; contextId: 0x0. But cannot find where triggered in the app. No crash.